# How do I delay one job offer long enough, so I can evaluate it against another job offer for a separate position in the same company?

Tags: salary, job-offer, recruitment, negotiation

I will be interviewed **by two separate positions** (similar job roles but serving different verticals of the business) for the **same employer** in South East Asia. (Employer is a fast-growing unicorn/tech company valued at > 1bn USD) .

I have two final round interviews for these two separate positions coming up this week. These two interviews are at separate days of the weeks (approx 2-3 days apart). Provided I pass both final rounds, I may get an offer for the first position 2-3 days before I get the offer for the second position.

**I want to delay the first offer long enough such that I have time to consider both offers together, which will help me pick one over the other**. However, I understand sometimes I may be pressured by the firm to accept the offer asap, and besides, I don't want to make them wait too long. How should I go about delaying this?

1. Is it fine if I tell the first position's HR/talent acquisition partner that I want X number of days to decide as I have another final round for another position in the same firm?
2. Should I just ask for 1 week to decide and not give any reason?
3. What should I do to 'play it nice' and not to offend anyone?

-just to indicate, each role is served by their own Talent acquisition parters/managers.

Answer (score 3):

When you have the offer letter for position A in hand, then you have a couple of options:

- Unless they need an immediate answer, tell them that you're considering other offers and you'd like a few days to decide. During that time you can hope that the recruiter for position B will move fast enough to get to the point where they send you an offer or...
- Inform the recruiter about position B that you're already far along the interview process for another position (no need to give specifics). If they're interested they will fast track the process and hopefully you can have an offer letter before the deadline for the other position ends so you can evaluate both.